# error on installation of opencv does not make sense

Tags: python, ruby, opencv, installation, homebrew

when I run `brew install opencv` I get the following error:

```
Error: undefined local variable or method `which_python' for #<Formula opencv (stable) /usr/local/Library/Formula/opencv.rb>
```

naturally I went to check this out by opening up `/usr/local/Library/Formula/opencv.rb`. That showed the following ruby declaration:

```
def which_python
  "python" + `python -c 'import sys;print(sys.version[:3])'`.strip
end
```

so `which_python` is clearly defined. Just to check and make sure that works, I opened up ruby to see if there was something wrong:

```
1.9.3-p194 :005 > def which_python
1.9.3-p194 :006?>     "python" + `python -c 'import sys;print(sys.version[:3])'`.strip
1.9.3-p194 :007?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3-p194 :008 > which_python
 => "python2.7"
```

This verifies that `which_python` is defined correctly. Can somebody please explain why this error is occurring and what I can do to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with:

```
rm /usr/local/Library/Formula/opencv.rb
brew update
brew doctor
brew install opencv
```

I'm not sure if removing opencv.rb is needed.